# Calling AJAX enabled web service by POST works but with GET it always return xml

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asmx, asp.net-4.0

I am calling in ASP.NET 4.0 web site a web service (asmx service in same web site) method in 2 different ways. The first method succeeds and always returns a valid JSON object when the asmx web service method is decorated with `[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]`.

But the second method fails because the data returned is XML rather than JSON, even though I have decorated the `asmx` method by `[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]`  (**I cannot understand why JSON is not being returned when using `GET` but it is when using `POST`?**)

- `POST` service call

  ```
  var serviceurl = "http://localhost:49441/WebService1.asmx/LoginUser" ;
  $.ajax({
      url: serviceurl,
       type: 'POST', 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       data: JSON.stringify({ userName: userName, password: password }),
       dataType: "json",
      success: function (msg) {
          alert('Web service call succeeded.  ' + msg.d);
      },
      error: function (error) { alert('ERROR has occurred!'); alert(JSON.stringify(error)) }
  });
  ```
- `GET` service call

  ```
  var serviceurl = "http://localhost:49441/WebService1.asmx/LoginUser" ;
  $.ajax({
      url: serviceurl,
       type: 'GET', 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       data: 'userName='+ userName + '&password=' + password,
       dataType: "json",
      success: function (msg) {
          alert('Web service call succeeded.  ' + msg.d);
      },
      error: function (error) { alert('ERROR has occurred!'); alert(JSON.stringify(error)) }
  });
  ```

---

- EDIT 1:

  The Web Service code is as below. When using `POST` I simply change code to use `UseHttpGet = false` for the method being called.

  ```
  [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
  [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
  [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
  // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
  [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

  public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService 
  {
      [WebMethod]
      [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Assert, Unrestricted = true)]
      [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
      public bool LoginUser(string userName, string password)
      {
          bool authenticated = false;

          if (userName.ToLower() == "mike" && password.ToLower() == "abcd") 
          {

              authenticated = true;
          }
          return authenticated;
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: The JS code makes no difference here. In order to understand why XML is returned instead of JSON when you post, we'd need to see either a) the web service code or b) the web service documentation.

Comment: Ok. Let me add the asmx web service code.

Comment: It could be that ajax enabled web service can only be called with a POST and not a GET from jQuery, but not sure.

Comment: @Sunil jQuery does not care what HTTP method you use. *This is not a client side problem.*

Comment: Ok.  When I call the same service method using standard JavaScript approach with ScriptManager, then it works fine and it uses GET behind the scenes when I check it in Fiddler.

Comment: @Tomalak - My earlier comment that using POST is necessary for calling ASP.Net ajax web service from jquery was indeed true. Read the answer I have given below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It appears that its necessary to use POST** according to what I read at the following URL in **Dave Ward's blog** [**Explanation on why POST is necessary if we are to receive JSON and not Xml when using jQuery**](http://encosia.com/asmx-and-json-common-mistakes-and-misconceptions/), else ASP.Net AJAX enabled web service may respond with XML even when its decorated to return JSON.  I have pasted the parts from the above URL that relate to my question.

(So the lesson I have learnt from all this, is to use POST when calling AJAX enabled web  services  i.e. asmx services,  from jQuery.)

> Two simple requirements
>
> As I alluded to earlier, the one stipulation is that these
>   ScriptServices only return JSON     serialized results if they are
>   requested properly. Otherwise, even a service marked with the
>   attribute will return XML instead of JSON. I can only assume that’s
>   part of the reason for the misconception that ASMX services cannot
>   respond with JSON.
>
> Scott Guthrie has a great post on the specific requirements for
>   coercing JSON out of ScriptServices. To summarize that, requests to
>   the service methods must meet two requirements:
>
> (1) Content-Type – **The HTTP request must declare a content-type of
>   application/json**. This informs the ScriptService that it will
>   receive its parameters as JSON and that **it should respond in kind.**
>
> (2) HTTP Method – **By default, the HTTP request must be a POST
>   request**. It is possible to circumvent this requirement, but it is
>   advisable to stick with HTTP POST requests when dealing with JSON.
>
> That’s it.
>
> **As long as those two requirements are satisfied, anything from low-level XMLHttpRequest code, to third-party libraries like jQuery**,
>   to ASP.NET AJAX itself can easily retrieve JSON serialized data from
>   ASMX services.

Comment: This is correct (glad you found my post). It always did feel a bit "wrong" to use POST for what are essentially resource GET requests, but the framework did that to ensure greater cross-site security by default at the time. To use GETs against a similar API (assuming you don't need SOAP), Web API is a great choice in newer apps. It works very similarly with the automatic serialization and everything, but supports GETs, more flexible input parameters with URL encoding, and is generally the standard approach going forward.

Comment: Dave - Your blogs are very useful/brilliant and contain information that is difficult to find elsewhere. Thanks.