# How to download stream returned from WCF service and that WCF service called from jquery ajax call

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json, wcf

I am consuming WCF Service Methods from client side using JQuery. I want to save the stream data which is returned from WCF method at client side. Following WCF method is working fine in which I am using our own excelExport's method to create memory stream -

```
public System.IO.Stream TestExportToExcel()
    {
        using (_oxBowData = new Data.OxbowDataContext())
        {
            ExcelExport excelExport = new ExcelExport();
            List<SheetData> sheets = new List<SheetData>();
            sheets.Add(new SheetData()
            {
                SheetName = "sheet1",
                DataList = _oxBowData.GetLunchReportData(new DateTime(2013, 12, 24)).ToList<object>()
            });
            using (MemoryStream xlsstream = excelExport.ExportToExcelToStream(sheets))
            {
                xlsstream.Position = 0L;
                return xlsstream;
            }
        }
    }
```

Service Contract:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "TestExportToExcel")]
System.IO.Stream TestExportToExcel();
```

Following is what I am using at Client side but it just returning me error-

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: u + "/Terminal/ManagementService.svc/TestExportToExcel",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                processData: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                }
            });
```

When I call this client side ajax call it returns error. Can anybody help?

Comment: can you change the request type from `"GET"` to `"POST"`. read it in a post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21224781/calling-ajax-enabled-web-service-by-post-works-but-with-get-it-always-return-xml

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem is that you are specifying `RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json` in JSON while your method `System.IO.Stream TestExportToExcel()` doesn't have any parameter to receive it.

Moreover! .NET enforces you to specify `RequestFormat` if you are using **POST** method. So, change your contract like this.

Your Service Contract.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", 
RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, 
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
UriTemplate   = "TestExportToExcel")]
System.IO.Stream TestExportToExcel(MyCustomObject jsonRequest);
```

Ajax:

```
type: "POST",
```

Comment: Chaning Get to Post does not help.